# I am unable to get the child names from given url in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift

In the api am getting global array but in this I am unable to get the children names as separate array only the last loaded array name has been getting in the array how to get the all children names in the array please help me how to get all the names in it and here is my code already tried

```
var detailsArray = NSArray()
var globalArray = NSMutableArray()
let url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cwqUAMjKGa?indent=2"
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
        {
            self.detailsArray = (jsonObj?.value(forKey: "data") as? [[String: AnyObject]])! as NSArray
            print(self.detailsArray)
            for item in self.detailsArray
            {
                let majorDic = NSMutableDictionary()
                let detailDict = item as! NSDictionary
                print(detailDict["name"]!)
                majorDic .setValue(detailDict["name"]!, forKey: "name")
                print(detailDict["children"]!)
                if !(detailDict["children"]! is NSNull)
                {
                    let children = detailDict["children"]! as! NSArray
                    let childrenstring = NSMutableString()
                    if children.count > 0 {
                        for item in children{
                            let chilDic = item as! NSDictionary
                            print(chilDic["name"]!)
                            print(chilDic["products"]!)
                            majorDic.setValue(chilDic["name"]!, forKey: "Childernname")
                            let products = chilDic["products"]! as! NSArray
                            if products.count > 0
                            {
                                for item in products
                                {
                                    var sr = String()
                                    sr = (item as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "name") as! String
                                    childrenstring.append(sr)
                                    childrenstring.append("*")
                                }
                                majorDic.setValue(childrenstring, forKey: "Childernproducts")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print("products.count\(products.count)")
                                majorDic.setValue("NO DATA", forKey: "Childernproducts")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("childernw.count\(children.count)")
                        majorDic.setValue("NO DATA", forKey: "Childernname")
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    majorDic.setValue("NO DATA", forKey: "Childernname")
                    majorDic.setValue("NO DATA", forKey: "Childernproducts")
                }
                self.globalArray.add(majorDic)
            }
            print("TOTAL ASSECTS\(self.globalArray)")
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print(self.globalArray)
                print(self.detailsArray)
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: can you please show your detailsArray?

Comment: its a big array and it consists what the api has @Yuyutsu

Comment: if u check in api u will get all those @Yuyutsu

Comment: Can you show what self.globalArray contains?please show the format

Comment: its a big array I can't display here you can see in api @user1000

Comment: the data is inserted in an array and the dict is there to display in it and in this all dictionaries childrenname key contains only one which is last loaded but I need to get all the names in children array like products array which is below @user1000

Comment: Please check my answer, see if it helps

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: no I was just checking ur answer now

Comment: yesterday I left office afternoon due to ill health @user1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var detailsArray = [DataList]()
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cwqUAMjKGa?indent=2")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
        {
            let objArr = (jsonObj?["data"]  as? [[String: AnyObject]])! as NSArray
            for obj in objArr {
                self.detailsArray.append(DataList(json: obj as! [String : AnyObject]))
            }
            print(self.detailsArray)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

**Model Class**

```
class DataList: NSObject {

    var count: Int
    var category_id: Int
    var childern:[Children]
    var name:String

    init (json: [String: AnyObject]){

        if let childrenList = json["children"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            var result = [Children]()
            for obj in childrenList {
                result.append(Children(json: obj))
            }
            self.childern = result
        } else {
            self.childern = [Children]()
        }

        if let count = json["count"] as? Int { self.count = count }
        else { self.count = 0 }
        if let category_id = json["category_id"] as? Int { self.category_id = category_id }
        else { self.category_id = 0 }
        if let name = json["name"] as? String { self.name = name }
        else { self.name = "" }
    }
}

class Children:NSObject{
    var count:Int
    var category_id:Int
    var products:[Products]
    var name:String

    init (json: [String: AnyObject]){

        if let productList = json["products"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            var result = [Products]()
            for obj in productList {
                result.append(Products(json: obj))
            }
            self.products = result
        } else {
            self.products = [Products]()
        }

        if let count = json["count"] as? Int { self.count = count }
        else { self.count = 0 }
        if let category_id = json["category_id"] as? Int { self.category_id = category_id }
        else { self.category_id = 0 }
        if let name = json["name"] as? String { self.name = name }
        else { self.name = "" }

    }
}


class Products:NSObject{
    var product_id:Int
    var name:String

    init (json: [String: AnyObject]){

        if let product_id = json["product_id"] as? Int { self.product_id = product_id }
        else { self.product_id = 0 }

        if let name = json["name"] as? String { self.name = name }
        else { self.name = "" }

    }
}
```

NOTE: Please check your data type while parsing

Comment: this model class I need to insert in same class or I need to take it in a separate foundation class ? @Yuyutsu

Comment: you can use both way, but use separate foundation class easy to understand you and your teammates.

Comment: I don't know how to take please tell me clearly one way ?@Yuyutsu

Comment: check it and let me know if there is any issue. @VamsiKrishnaSurathi

Comment: bro I checked your answer now yesterday I left office in afternoon due to ill health

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152691/discussion-between-yuyutsu-and-vamsi-krishna-surathi).

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. Instead of using for loop try using flatMap() and then extract the value using `value(forKey: " ")` function

```
let productNames = productValues.flatMap() {$0.value}   
let names = (productNames as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name")
```

It had worked for me for my json. My Json was similar to yours. 
I got separate values in array.

Comment: how to use flatMap() I don't know ?

Comment: you are getting `Kickboard Facia` repeated right?? in the array

Comment: {
        Childernname = Kickboards;
        Childernproducts = "Base End Panel*Wall End Panel*Pantry End Panel*Base Filler*Wall Filler*Pantry Filler*Kickboard Base*Kickboard Facia*";
        name = "Panels & Fillers";
    }

Comment: in this children name I am getting only one which is astroturfing loaded but I am unable to get all names in children and in children products I am getting all data @Bella

Comment: `products` is the value of first Array<Dictionary> and key of second Array<Dictionary>.  see the updated answer

Comment: Actually your json is too big. To iterate over `products` you must have taken Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>. so productValues is array. I thought you just want the names of `products` key.

Comment: Data separation is very important. Make another class like mentioned by @ Yuyutsu. You can name it as DataListModel.swift